# iPhone app - Review guidelines - Contest rules

Tags: iphone

i've just had my iPhone app rejected on the 20.2 statement of the Review Guidelines:

Official rules for sweepstakes and contests, must be presented in the app and make it clear that Apple is not a sponsor or involved in the activity in any manner

Now, I have a problem. In my app I will have more than one contest, even if all based on the same ground rules. Can I put these rules in the app (like in a UITextField) taking them dynamically form a server? In this manner I could specify, for exemple, the specific period of time each contest would last without having to chose them right now... Do you think that this would be accepted or I have to put those rules directly in the bundle?

Thank you

Comment: I think that'd be ok... as long as the user cannot access/register for the contest page without having an active Internet connection. (throw a UIAlertView saying they need a connection to access this content, etc)

Comment: I agree with @luke. The most important thing is that the reviewer is forced to read the terms before they can enter the competition. Make sure that your server has a reasonable rule set in place when you submit!

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Maybe you should speak with legal counsel who specialize in gambling laws.

Answer (score 2):

it would definitely be accepted...
but, a web view would be better than a text field... open an html hosted on your server in the web view. You can add rules and declaration that apple is not involved in any way in that html and change it whenever you want... with html you'd be able to add images (or even videos .. HTML5?)...
you can also include a default html in your app which would open when theres no connectivity...

Answer (score -3):

In way you have already done you are able to violate apple guidelines at any moment.

Consider updating your app instead of downloading contests from server.